# Remove spaces and line breaks of a xml file

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010

I receive from a webservice a xml file but it comes with line breaks and spaces between the tags, and i need to remove them and put the xml in a string in a single line.
I already tried with TXMLDocument, but i only i could only replace the spaces for a tab.

Exemple of xml:

```
<CompNfse xmlns="http://www.sistema.com.br/Nfse/arquivos/nfse_3.xsd">'#$D#$A'      <Nfse versao="">'#$D#$A'        <InfNfse Id=" 00000000000670">'#$D#$A'          <Numero>10</Numero>.....
```

Using TXMLDocument

```
<CompNfse xmlns="http://www.sistema.com.br/Nfse/arquivos/nfse_3.xsd">'#$D#$A#9'<Nfse versao="">'#$D#$A#9#9'<InfNfse Id=" 00000000000670">'#$D#$A#9#9#9'<Numero>10</Numero>....
```

How i need

```
<CompNfse xmlns="http://www.sistema.com.br/Nfse/arquivos/nfse_3.xsd"><Nfse versao=""><InfNfse Id=" 00000000000670"><Numero>10</Numero>....
```

The code i tried.

```
var sTemp : String;
oXml : TXMLDocument;
begin
  try
    sTemp := '<Nfse versao="">'+#13#10+'        <InfNfse Id=" 00000000000670">'+#13#10+'          <Numero>10</Numero>'+#13#10+'              <CodigoVerificacao>82557.2TE79</CodigoVerificacao></InfNfse></Nfse>';
    oXml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    oXml.Options := [];
    oXml.ParseOptions := [];
    oXml.LoadFromXML(sTemp);
    sTemp := oXml.XML.Text;
  finally
    oXml := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why on earth would you "need" force the XML onto a single line? **(1)** The XML standard specifically requires that whitespace can be added or removed without affecting the meaning of the data. **(2)** If you (or a client) have an XML Parser that cannot handle extra whitespace: ***Get rid of that parser!*** Using a substandard parser will just make life difficult in the long run. **(3)** There's actually an advantage to XML with spaces and line break: In a pinch, it's readable in bad editors like Notepad.... _You should never fuss about the formatting of your XML - it's a waste of time_.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the whitespace?  It is legal XML, you can still parse it.

Comment: Because i need to use a third-party component to read the xml and doesn't read the data with the spaces and brake lines.

Comment: Whitespace handling has been in the XML from the beginning. If the component is not conformant enough to ignore it, find another component.

Comment: Rigotti I agree with @Remy : If the the third-party component cannot handle ***valid*** XML, then don't use the component. Or contact the vendor and tell them to fix it. Seriously, it is _not worth your time_ to compensate for the vendor's mistakes. Anything you do will simply complicate your own processes: slowing things down and increasing the chance of bugs.... Please listen to my advice: it's ***for your own benefit***.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,@CraigYoung I even agree with you, but in this case, although the component is open source, it is huge,and already work for other scenarios so I would lose a lot more time changing the component than looking for a solution to change the xml

Comment: @Rigotti: If the component is open source, then you can freely modify it and add the necessary whitespace handling to it. Then submit the changes to the author if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `doNodeAutoIndent` flag from the `TXMLDocument.Options` property, and the `poPreserveWhiteSpace` flag from the `TXMLDocument.ParseOptions` property.

Comment: did not work or I'm doing something wrong. added code to the question

Comment: Change the `ParseOptions` *before* loading the XML, not *after*. Changing the parsing options is useless if you do it after parsing is done. Also, read the `TXMLDocument` documentation. When you create an instance of `TXMLDocument` with a nil Owner, it acts as a reference counted interface, so you need to use an `IXMLDocument` variable, not a `TXMLDocument` variable, to maintain that reference count. Your code is leaking the `TXMLDocument` object, assuming it is not running into other problems with internal references on the parsed nodes.